# Is there a way to add a domain for TLS with linuxserver/letsencrypt / linuxserver/swag at runtime?

Tags: docker, ssl, tls1.2, lets-encrypt

I have a site using linuxserver/letsencrypt ( I know this also needs to be switched to swag at some point) which has a main domain and three subdomains specified with the following environment variables in the docker-compose file:

```
  - URL=mysite.com
  - SUBDOMAINS=app1,app2,app3
```

However, I would like to add functionality that allows me to host pages for other domains which users can point their DNS to.

As an example, I will be hosting a custom landing page for each user on my site which needs to run on this server as it features login/interaction etc. The user will normally have 2 DNS records:

```
theirsite.com > pointing to their own server
landing-page.theirsite.com > pointing to my server
```

And on my side obviously:

```
mysite.com > pointing to my server
```

It's probably worth noting that this will not always be a subdomain, so the following is also possible:

```
theirsite.com > pointing to their own server
theirshop.com > pointing to my server
```

On my server I already have the software setup to detect the url and show the relevant user-generated landing page. However, as I am using Let's Encrypt to generate the TLS for my main site I would also like to use it for these user-entered domains if possible.

I've seen that I can specify additional domains using EXTRA_DOMAINS and that I could use a file as an input for this. However, I understand that this would require a restart to take effect.

So it really all boils down to:

1. is there a way to add extra domains whilst the docker container is running without interruption to the main site?
2. is there a way to keep these certificates on reboot like the environment variable specified ones?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to do this, after a lot of research and talking to the linuxserver/letsencrypt devs, we are now using https://caddyserver.com/ for this which is very easy to setup.